# UIpicker array with changing values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

I'm making an app that uses the picker to let the user pick age and few other inputs. for eg: i have a button age, when the user clicks it, the picker shows the age. i managed to add individual picker for all the inputs, how ever i'm having problems setting different arrays for each picker.

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component { 
    if (pickerview == picker) {
        return [pickerViewArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else if (pickerview == stagepicker)
        return [stagepickerarray objectAtInde:row];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (thePickerView == picker){ return [pickerViewArray count]; }
    else if (thePickerView == stagepicker){ [stagepickerarray count]; }
}
```

the above method isn't working for me !. Am I doing this right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component { 
    if (pickerview == picker) {
```

Doesn't it sound like `pickerview` should be written `thePickerView` instead?

```
return [stagepickerarray objectAtInde:row];
```

Doesn't it sound like `objectAtInde` should be `objectAtIndex`?

```
else if (thePickerView == stagepicker){ [stagepickerarray count]; }
```

Doesn't it sound like a `return` is missing somewhere?

Comment: oh god ! that was an epic fail typo on my part !.

Comment: In these three cases, XCode should have alerted you by emitting warnings. You'll soon learn to recognize typos by that means.

Comment: My array is empty even though i have given it values ! here is what i have done so far. the .h file

Answer (score 0):

Why not use one UIPickerView with multiple components? Something along the lines of:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

NSInteger numberOfRows;

if (component == 0) {
     numberOfRows = [anArray count];
}
else if(component == 1) { 
    numberOfRows = [anotherArray count];
}
else { 
    numberOfRows = [aThirdArray count];
}

return numberOfRows;

}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

NSString *stringIndex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TEST"];
if(component == 0) {

   return stringIndex = [anArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

else if(component == 1) {
    return stringIndex = [anotherArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

else {
   return stringIndex = [aThirdArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

return stringIndex;

}
```

Comment: so you are saying use one UIpicker with different arrays ? I'll have a go at this and let you know how it goes !

Comment: Yup, I'm working on a something similar right now, and that's how you do it. Here's a good tutorial: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_4_iPad_Multiple_Component_UIPickerView_Example_(Xcode_4)

Comment: I you scroll all the way down, you see that they made a UIPickerView with 2 components, and 2 hard-coded arrays.